# Matlab: Limit as t approaches positive and negative infinity?

Tags: matlab, math, limit, infinity

I'm trying to write some code which would find the limit of a function as x approaches positive and negative infinity. The code I have so far is as follows:

```
pos = limit(exp(atan(x)), x = infinity)
neg = limit(exp(atan(x)), x = -infinity)
```

However, it gives me an error saying "invalid syntax at =. Possibly, a ), }, or ] is missing. When I looked at the Matlab documentation for how to compute a limit, they had this as their example:

```
limit((1 + 1/n)^n, n = infinity)
```

and this returned an answer of e. When I put this into my own Matlab, it gave me the same error, could anyone help? Is it possibly an error with my Matlab?

Comment: Pretty sure the accepted syntax is `inf` for infinity. Check out http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've been looking at the wrong help. Such notation (and `limit` function) is used in MuPAD interface, not in the simple Matlab Command Window.
To use `limit()` in Matlab environment, you have to use symbolic variables and [this](http://it.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/limit.html) is the correct help page.

In other words, to compute

```
limit((1 + 1/n)^n, n = infinity)
```

you have to declare a symbolic variable `n`

```
syms n
```

and then provide the correct syntax (ref. help)

```
limit((1 + 1/n)^n, n, inf)
```

and the result is (of course) `exp(1)`, that is *e*.

Comment: Nice catch! I was wondering where the documentation would have used "infinity".

Comment: Indeed. That's why the MuPAD idea occurred to me. Sometimes MuPAD and Matlab have functions with the same name...dear Mathworks you fooled me several times as well, I must admit.

Comment: Oh, I looked back at the help that I originally referred to and realized there was a huge thing that said that it only worked in MuPAD... awkward... but thanks!